# Why is getting a value from a variable preferred than getting it from an array?

Tags: java, arrays, variables, optimization

Consider the below program:

```
int []array = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50};
int x = array[0];
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
{
 System.out.println(x * array[i]);
 System.out.println(array[0] * array[i]);
}
```

When an array is declared, it is stored in the memory which reside together.

```
array:     [0]    [1]    [2]    [3]   [4]
Value:     10     20     30     40    50
Location:  100   102     104    106   108
```

Now when x is assigned a value which is the first element of the `array(10)`.

`x` is stored a value in the memory with value `10`.

```
variable :  x
Value :     10
Location :  120
```

Now when we call the for loop,

The first print statement will refer to the value at location `120` and say that I have a value `10`.

The second print statement will also refer to a location `100` and say it has a value `10`.

When both the statements have to look for the memory location every time, why would the first statement be more optimal?

**EDIT**
In the same program if `x` is used multiple times.

```
int []array = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50};
int x = array[0];
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
{
 System.out.println(x * array[i] + (x + 1) * array[i] - ( x + 2));
 System.out.println(array[0] * array[i] + (array[0] + 1) * array[i] - (array[0] + 2));
}
```

Here x is used many times. So people prefer using `x` than calling array[0] everytime.

Both have to be looked up though.

Comment: I suppose you eliminate duplicate memory accesses if you have a dumb compiler.

Comment: If we are speaking about unoptimized compilation, Java checks the range of array index at each indexation.

Comment: Why do you think one is more optimal than the other? Also, this could be different in Java and C. Do you really want to tag with both languages?

Comment: Who says it's more optimal?

Comment: It's not optimization preference, they have the same complexity~, it's the obey the DRY principle. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself

Comment: because we are not accessing arrays directly, First jvm is searching array's reference then created array object which is at different location (mostly in heap). however local variable reside in stack. so obviously variable will be more efficient.@UmaKanth

Comment: This questions fails the [97/3 rule](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization): *not interesting.*

Comment: @user2864740 I was just curious why is that more preferred. I was told by my superior not to do so. I was wondering why he told me to do so.

Comment: I suggest the first statement more optimal when compared to the second one as because every time the compiler needs to point the zeroth index of an array instead of directly pointing to a memory using the variable label.

Comment: I find it hard to believe that there is any measuranle performance difference between the two versions in more than 0.1% of the time. So imho that decision should be made based on code clarity and/or consistency - based not on performance arguments. But why not ask the guy who gave you the advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When accessing `array[i]`, the processor has to look up the memory address for `array` and then add `i` to that address to get to the variable you requested.

When accessing `x` the processor can get the variable directly from `x`.

In Java, only primitives are stored on the stack so `array` will be a pointer to something on the heap whereas `x` will be stored on the stack. This only applies if `x` is a primitive though. If `array` contains objects (and `x` is thus a pointer to an object), both will be stored on the heap.

So the main difference is that when accessing `array[i]` you'll be accessing *location-of-array-plus-i*, but when accessing `x` you'll be accessing *location-of-x*. It's worth noting that `array[0]` (or any other fixed index) can usually be optimised into a single instruction.

Now, should you worry about this? No, absolutely not. There is unlikely to even be a measurable performance difference between these two ways and even if there is it is extremely unlikely that the performance difference will affect you - your application is probably doing a lot more time-consuming work than just accessing variables in memory. The compiler will also very likely optimise this to reduce the number of memory lookups required and the processor caches will play a role too.

The real reason it is preferable to write something like:

```
int x = array[0]
int y = array[1]
int result = x + y + x * y + x * (x - y)
```

Is that it is a lot more readable than:

```
int result = array[0] + array[1] + array[0] * array[1] + array[0] * (array[0] - array[1])
```

Comment: I completely agree with your answer. Maybe you could also mention that loading from and address plus a fixed offset can usually be compiled into a single instruction. And that the compiler might be able to do those transformations on its own anyway.